# Call JSON wcf service via jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf

I have question according calling json wcf methods from aspx page with jQuery.

This is my test method:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IEParcelService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "Test")]
        Response<string> Test();
    }

  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public class EParcelServiceImpl : IEParcelService
  {    
    public Response<string> Test()
    {
      return WebServiceHelper.Execute(() => "Test Message");
    }    
  }
```

This service deployed to IIS. 
When I call this method from Chrome: http://localhost/TestService/ServiceImpl.svc/Test
Everything is ok and I can see the result. But when I call it from jQuery 
I have error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101. I try to find solution in Google.
But the result was not successful. How I can solve it?

jQuery call:

```
<script language="javascript">
  $().ready(function () {
            $("#myButt").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost/EParselService/EParcelServiceImpl.svc/Test",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                  success: function (data, textStatus){
                                alert('successCallBack called');
                                alert(data);
                                alert(textStatus);
                         },
                   error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('errorCallBack called');
                            alert('textStatus = ' + textStatus + '/nerrorThrown = ' + errorThrown);
                        } 
                 });
                alert('Done!');
            });
        });
</script>

<input type="button" value="Get values from server" id="myButt" />
```

Comment: It's probably a cross-site problem. Do you host your html on the same iis? Have a look here: http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/.

Comment: I hosted service on IIS, but my test website I run on Visual Studio Development Server.

Comment: Well there you go you should host them both on the same site. if you want to use the XMLHttpRequest, because it's not allowed to open recourse out of it's scope. This is to prevent XSS atacks. If you want to use a recourse from a different site you'll have to use something like jsonp (see like I posted before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's a same-origin issue. (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy))

For a XMLHttpRequest the resource has to be on the exact same domain as the page requesting it. This is to prevent XSS (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)) atacks. If you want to use a resource from a different domain you'll have to use something like jsonp. (see [here](http://pranayamr.blogspot.nl/2011/06/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html)) For a good tutorial how to do this with WCF.

Comment: The link you provided is no longer active.

Comment: @PsychoDUCK I fixed the link. The blog post I orignally provided was no longer available. But I found another one which basically provides the same information